# Default vue app is not loading on localhost

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Today I decided to start learning vue. So I installed the CLI and created a new Vue application using the following template: ([Vue 2] typescript, router, vuex, eslint). After the application was created, I opened the development server using npm run serve. Here comes my problem. I go to localhost:8080 and nothing loads up. As I can see it is in a continuous loop and never finishes loading.
I tried to open it in another browser with no success, I get the same result.
I don't exactly know what code I should show you because as I said, it is the default application with nothing changed.
Thanks for reading this!

Comment: what does your terminal say?

Comment: It says it compiled successful. You know, that success message and the ip where I can see the app. I go to that address and it stucks on loading

Comment: try to see if the app runs on `http` or `https`

Comment: I tried both https://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:8080 and the result is the same for both.

Comment: After I restarted my computer it worked. I didn't do any change in the code. Just restarted the computer and started the server again